# Function Similar with to_char(datetime) that can be used both Oracle and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Function Similar with `to_char(datetime)` that can be used both Oracle and MySQL?

I want to generate the ANSI SQL script to run both in oracle and in MySQL.
But, the generated ANSI SQL is working well. except the the error from to_char().

Is there any function that can be used in both db?

Comment: Do you need to format dates or cast numbers to string?

Comment: I need to format dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date formatting abilities couldn't be more different. I think your best chance is to pick one of these:

1. Run an `ALTER SESSION` statement when you connect to Oracle to replicate the MySQL default date format and do all date formatting in your client app.
2. Write a custom wrapper function and use it in your queries. You have to fork function code and maintain two versions.

You still have DBMS-dependent code but it's isolated in your initialisation code (option #1) or your installation script (option #2).

Perhaps there's a third option: tweak your database abstraction library to detect column types in result sets and convert dates to custom objects (e.g., `DateTime` if you use PHP, `Date` if you use JavaScript, etc.).

Comment: Maybe I will make two version of queries. It will execute on runtime.

Comment: Well, I thought you were trying to avoid that xD

Comment: Yes I was I wanted one query. But even if I translate ansi sql,  it has many db vendor specific functions.

Comment: If one or two are all,  I will use wrapper method.  But it is not

Answer (score 0):

Mysql and Oracle uses different syntax for converting date to string.
You should use different queries.